# Where to find "poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.jar" Javadoc and sources jar?

Tags: netbeans, apache-poi, javadoc

I am working with Apache POI (Version : 3.15) Word in Netbeans. It's function does not show any Javadoc. By clicking Attach Javadoc in  Netbeans says

> "No Javadoc for "poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.jar" available

Searched but no Javadoc jar or sources jar either have been found. Would anyone please provide me something where to find them ?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Apache POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10192):

> **I can't seem to find the source for the OOXML CT.. classes, where do they come from?**
>
> The OOXML support in Apache POI is built on top of the file format XML Schemas, as compiled into Java using XMLBeans. Currently, the compilation is done with XMLBeans 2.3, for maximum compatibility with installations. (You can use the resulting classes on the XMLBeans 2.3 runtime, or any later version of XMLBeans. If you are currently using XMLBeans 2.2 or earlier, you will unfortunately have to upgrade, but this isn't common any more).
>
> All of the org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006 CT... classes are auto-generated by XMLBeans. The resulting generated Java goes in the ooxml-schemas-src jar, and the compiled version into the ooxml-schemas jar.
>
> The full ooxml-schemas jar is distributed with Apache POI, along with the cut-down poi-ooxml-schemas jar containing just the common parts. The source jar isn't normally distributed with POI. It is, however, available from Maven Central - ask your favourite Maven mirror for the ooxml-schemas-src jar. Alternately, if you download the POI source distribution (or checkout from SVN) and build, Ant will automatically download the specification XML Schema, and compile it for you to generate the source and binary ooxml-schemas jars.

So, if you really want the source, you can grab the source code for Apache POI and use the build tools to recreate the auto-generated source files. If you want the docs, you need to go and read the published Microsoft file format documentation, as the ooxml-schemas jars are just auto-generated from the published specs!

Answer (score 1):

There's a Javadoc jar build available from the central Maven repo:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi/3.15/

Should this happen to go offline, you could have your IDE search through known Maven repositories for POI Javadoc artifacts, or alternatively download the source code for the version you use and have the docs built from that.

The source code for apache projects is usually available via their project page, like here: https://poi.apache.org/download.html (section source distribution).